# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS "lib/systemd/systemd-journald" using too much CPU

Tags: root, ubuntu-16.04

I am new to using **Linux**.
The process **lib/systemd/systemd-journald** is taking up `30-60%` of my CPU. I don't know how to stop it. And I do not know how to look for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a process for the system's journal. Someone ever was hit by this issue too, which might be related to your system's file changing too fast.His solved it by deleting the file ".kde4/share/apps/nepomuk",you can have a try.

Comment: I am getting **.kde4/share/apps/nepomuk: No such file or directory**. Is there a way I can get a system report or something?

Comment: As far as I'm concern, you should firstly try to figure out which process made the journald process occupy the CPU in that high rate, maybe you could try the command 'journalctl'.